# Combining pictures with python

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Im currently working on a project where an object is placed on a 60cm x 60cm plate. This plate is divided into 4 sections where every section is 30cm x 30cm. Every section has its own camera that photoghraphs this 30cm x 30cm section (Actually its 31cm x 31cm so that the sections overlap a bit to eliminate the risk of missing some part):

[image: plate division]

I want to combine the pictures into 1 picture via python as if just 1 picture was taken from above.
So the result should like this (note that the picture of the whole tool is just a picture I took and not edited together from the 4 single pictures):

Input:

Top Left:
[image: top left]

Top Right:
[image: top right]

Bottom Left:
[image: bottom left]

Bottom Right:
[image: bottom right]

Expected output:
[image: combined pictures]

On the pictures I placed green cords to show the 30cm x 30cm segments.

Additional Info: The tool is placed on a LED panel to increase contrast. Also markers, for example black lines that divide the sections, could be placed if this opens new possibilities to code. This could look something like this:

[image: Black lines to divide the sections]

Comment: Cool - what was your question please? Which parts of the code have you got worked out - please add them to your question. Which parts do you need some help with? If the idea of the project is to generate a higher quality image by combining 4 images, you should look first at getting the exposure correct - your images are currently underexposed so you will get noise in the shadow (dark) areas. You will also need to think about rotational correction, and perspective distortion because the cameras are in different places and exposure matching between different cameras.

Comment: Should probaly add the question at the end. I want to know how to approach this problem. I have limited knowledge so my problem is that I dont know where to start. Some of the research I have done suggests using OpenCV to merge the pictures together but maybe there are other better solutions to my problem. Right now I cant get better exposed pictures, could try to get them next week.

Comment: IMHO, **OpenCV** is the best way to go about this. Get it loaded on your machine, read some code examples and get together enough code to open your 4 images and create a new blank canvas 2x the width and 2x the height and paste the 4 images in the 4 corners, then come back for more help.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep you updated :)